# Execute a stored procedure within a trigger in sql server with parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers, insert

I have created a trigger which will execute a stored procedure on INSERT:

```
USE [DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
 ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_name] ON [dbo].[table_name]
  AFTER INSERT AS
  BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    EXEC procedure_name_exec param1, param2, param3
  END
```

what I want to achieve is to execute the stored procedure with parameters which represent the row that has been just inserted and which basically triggered this trigger.

Comment: thanks for the edit @TheGameiswar

Comment: Since the parameters need to be values from the row(s) being inserted you are going to have to use a loop here because the inserted table can and will have more than 1 row. You will need to call this procedure for each row.

Comment: I don't want a loop, the trigger should execute the procedure each time a row is inserted.

Comment: That isn't how triggers work in sql server. They once per operation not once per row. If you have an insert that inserts more than 1 row and your trigger doesn't handle each row your logic is not going to work correctly.

Comment: The operation is an insert and the insert is for one row. Therefore i don't need a loop

Comment: Do what you will, but if your trigger is an insert and it ignores the very likely possibility of multiple rows, the carnage is on you. I have known of at least one company that literally closed its doors because their triggers blindly assumed there would only ever be a single row. The cost to fix all their triggers was too much and they closed the doors. The reality is that yes you do need a loop if you must execute a procedure.

Comment: I'm not sure if I have explained my problem very well but i have posted the solution i was looking for.

Comment: @Claritta   -  You are not understanding DML .   It is not always a 1:1  , You can easily find out from the architects of sql server , the gurus that are working on the DDL / DML ,    This is why loops are necessary with it

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and here is how I solved it.

```
USE [DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
 ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_name] ON [dbo].[table_name]
  AFTER INSERT AS
  BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @nRows INT;
    DECLARE @var1 DATETIME;
    DECLARE @InsertedDates TABLE (
        NewDate DATETIME
    );

    INSERT INTO @InsertedDates
    SELECT [column name]
    FROM INSERTED;

    SELECT @nRows = COUNT(*) FROM @InsertedDates;

    WHILE @nRows > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @var1 = NewDate FROM @InsertedDates;

        EXEC    procedure_name_exec @var1;

        DELETE FROM @InsertedDates 
        WHERE @var1 = NewDate;

        SELECT @nRows = COUNT(*) FROM @InsertedDates;
    END;
  END;
```

The general idea is to recognize that `Inserted` is a table and you will need to process each row. I did this by making a copy of the table (not sure that was necessary) and processing the table variable, then delete the rows I processed from my table variable.

*Note*: if it is important to handle inserted duplicates then you will need to count them and call the stored procedure multiple times.

Answer (score -2):

Here is what  was looking for and gave me the result I was looking for:

```
USE [DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
 ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_name] ON [dbo].[table_name]
  AFTER INSERT AS
  BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    declare @var1 DATETIME
    SELECT @var1 = inserted.[column name] 
    FROM inserted

    EXEC procedure_name_exec @var1
  END
```

Comment: This is flawed logically because the inserted table is a table, not a set of scalar values. If what you are capturing from the procedure is relevant to the row data then you have a major problem in your code here.